# Citation automation software that correctly formats legal citations?

Tags: windows, reference-management, legal

I have tried Mendeley for citations and bibliography for writing law papers at my university, but it seems not to be designed for legal citations.

For example, when I want to add a Case file as an item in Mendeley, and choose "case" as the item's type, it asks for "volume" rather than "case number", which causes the citation to be incorrectly formatted.

So which citation program is well-adapted to legal citations? Which program(s) should I use?

e.g. I'm using a citation style like OSCALA or Bluebook.

Answer (score 2):

[Easybib](http://www.easybib.com/) is a web site that can handle many different citations. OSCOLA and Bluebook are only available from the $9.99 monthly premium account, however.

P.S:

> e.g. I'm using a citation style like OSCALA or Bluebook.

Perhaps you meant [OSCOLA](https://www.law.ox.ac.uk/research-subject-groups/publications/oscola)?